# The GitHub and Twitter links are obscured in the new layout

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

#### Update

I think I've changed my mind. It is not that bad.

---

With the new layout of the profile page, the GitHub and Twitter icons are so small and occupy just a tiny space which makes them hard to find and click.

I think they should be accompanied with a text or have a little more margin from each other.

[image]

Comment: It might be more effective to post this as an answer on [We’ve shipped some changes to the user profile navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369276/271271).

Comment: @TylerH I think I should have posted this as an answer as the other comment mentioned.

Comment: For what it’s worth I like the icons like this.

Comment: I guess they could do with making those links a little more obvious. Perhaps larger or with extra margins. It looks a little cluttered to me now. But I'm not really bothered by it. I'd prefer to hear from someone with accessibility issues though, I wonder how this design affects them.

Comment: Is there still a field to enter your GitHub username? Or just a link? I can't remember how it was before.

Comment: @TylerH there's a text field under `Settings` -> `Edit profile`

Comment: A considerable part of my problem with it is that just the icons aren't understandable as to what they are, what they mean, or that *that particular icon* is clickable, while all the other icons, which are visually very similar and clearly grouped together, are *not* clickable. Another point is that the prior organization on the page was very ordered. My eyes could go directly to where the piece of data was always going to be. With a horizontal presentation, my eyes have to *hunt* for whatever it is I'm looking for, each and every time, because there's no longer a set position.

Comment: The CSS: `body.user-page #mainbar-full .list-reset.s-anchors.s-anchors__inherit.d-flex.fc-light.gs8.mln4.fw-wrap > .flex--item > a[title]:after { content: attr(title); }` was sufficient to have the content of the tooltips be displayed after the icon for these. The selector can almost certainly be optimized, but I haven't taken the time to look through the user pages to see what, if anything, has something close that might be impacted by using a less verbose selector.

Comment: @aheze So the value is still stored, just not shown on the page?

Comment: After some considerable effort, I found the Stack Apps app by [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte) that purports to solve some of these problems: https://stackapps.com/questions/9080/make-better-use-of-the-space-in-profiles-like-profiles-used-to-be I'm not sure why he didn't bother linking directly to it in his now-deleted comment about it.